# Different ways to load data in ARM assembly language?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am to assembly language. I am coding it in a raspberry PI. I am currently trying to load data from memory to register. I followed this source for guidance:
https://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/11/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-3/

Here's the code:

```
/* -- load01.s */

/* -- Data section */
.data

/* Ensure variable is 4-byte aligned */
.balign 4
/* Define storage for myvar1 */
myvar1:
    /* Contents of myvar1 is just 4 bytes containing value '3' */
    .word 3

/* Ensure variable is 4-byte aligned */
.balign 4
/* Define storage for myvar2 */
myvar2:
    /* Contents of myvar2 is just 4 bytes containing value '4' */
    .word 4

/* -- Code section */
.text

/* Ensure code is 4 byte aligned */
.balign 4
.global main
main:
    ldr r1, addr_of_myvar1 /* r1 ← &myvar1 */
    ldr r1, [r1]           /* r1 ← *r1 */
    ldr r2, addr_of_myvar2 /* r2 ← &myvar2 */
    ldr r2, [r2]           /* r2 ← *r2 */
    add r0, r1, r2         /* r0 ← r1 + r2 */
    bx lr

/* Labels needed to access data */
addr_of_myvar1 : .word myvar1
addr_of_myvar2 : .word myvar2
```

However, upon more research, I realise that there's another way of doing it. I just use the **=** operator to load the address directly into a register

```
/* -- Data section */
.data

/* Ensure variable is 4-byte aligned */
.balign 4
/* Define storage for myvar1 */
myvar1:
    /* Contents of myvar1 is just 4 bytes containing value '3' */
    .word 3

/* Ensure variable is 4-byte aligned */
.balign 4
/* Define storage for myvar2 */
myvar2:
    /* Contents of myvar2 is just 4 bytes containing value '4' */
    .word 4

/* -- Code section */
.text

/* Ensure code is 4 byte aligned */
.balign 4
.global main
main:
    ldr r1, =myvar1 /* r1 ← &myvar1 */
    ldr r1, [r1]           /* r1 ← *r1 */
    ldr r2, =myvar2 /* r2 ← &myvar2 */
    ldr r2, [r2]           /* r2 ← *r2 */
    add r0, r1, r2         /* r0 ← r1 + r2 */
    bx lr
```

My question is:

1. what's the difference between these two methods?
2. which is the preferred method?
3. How do I change this such that I can decide which memory address to load/write data to/from?

Comment: The `=myvar1` invents a nearby constants (aka literal pool) for you.  The actual machine code will be very similar either way, using a PC-relative load to get the 32-bit address of something farther away.  That data-section address would otherwise take more instructions to generate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, thanks for the reply! I will stick to the =myvar1 method. I have another question, If I want to load/write data from a specific memory address (0x01001003), how do I go about it?

Comment: `ldr r1, =0x01001003` is the obvious way to get that address into a register, exactly like a symbol address...  If you want to optimize some, it might be possible to get part of it with a single mov-immediate, and use the rest as an offset for `ldr`, but probably not since there are 3 separate groups of bits far from each other.

Comment: the =label/address method is not assumed to be supported by all assemblers.  Certainly gnu where it has the most features from what I can tell.  and the assumption is that being on a pi you are using gnu assembler

Comment: `ldr r1, =myvar1` is actually a pseudo instruction. It assembles to `ldr r1, [pc, #n]`. Neither one is any faster than the other one.